# Не все пути кода возращают значение

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cqrs, mediatr

Имеется проект в котором испоьзуется MediatR (CQRS)

В контроллере, который должен возвращать поток данных (экспорт таблицы в Excel). Возникает ошибка: CS0661 не все пути возращают значение

Пример кода контроллера

```
  public async Task<FileContentResult> ExportGeneralReport([FromBody] GetGeneralExcelReportRequest vm)
    {
        await Mediator.Send(new GetGeneralExcelReportRequest
        {
            Date = vm.Date,
            ...
        });
    }
```

Пример кода QueryHadler

```
internal class GetGeneralExcelReportQueryHandler : ControllerBase, IRequestHandler<GetGeneralExcelReportRequest, FileContentResult>
{
    public Task<FileContentResult> Handle(GetGeneralExcelReportRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        FileContentResult result;
        List<string> _list = new();
        using (IXLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("GeneralReport");
            var currentRow = 1;

            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "Дата";
            ...
            foreach(var item in _list)
            {
                currentRow++;
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = item.date;
                ...
            }
            #endregion
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                result = File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.xlsx");
                return Task.FromResult(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема возника после того как я унаследовал ControllerBase. Нужно ли его вообще наследовать в этом случае ?
Я это сделал для того , чтобы File для передачи файла использовался из ControllerBase , а не из System.IO.

Или подскажите как коректно передать созданный файл на фронт

Comment: Вам ведь ошибка прямым текстом говорит, что у вас не так, а студия прям подсвечивает проблемное место. Неужели не понятно, в чем дело? `public async Task<FileContentResult> ExportGeneralReport(...){}` - что тут видите? Возвращаемый тип `Task<FileContentResult>`, а где хотя бы один `return` в методе, который вернет этот тип?

Comment: _для того , чтобы File для передачи файла использовался из ControllerBase , а не из System.IO_ - метод [ControllerBase.File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0) и класс [File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) не имеют между собой ничего общего, не смотря на название.

Comment: -Да ошибка говорит прямым текстом и студия подчеркивет. Но студия подчеркивает название контроллера. В самом Handler ошибки не вылазят.
Переменная result имеет тип FileContentResult в приведенном примере это переменная , обернутая в Task.FromResult(); и возращается

-То что File разные я знеаю. Я по этому внизу и пояснил для чего я подцепил BaseController

Comment: `и возращается` - самый первый код в вопросе, метод `ExportGeneralReport` - это что? Он используется у вас, или это псевдокод чисто для вопроса? Если используется, где `return`?

Comment: Вот это я опростоволосился. Нет, это не псевдокод. Там единственное. что принимается 1 обхект вместо списка. Этот контроллер скопирован с контроллера формирования отчета. 
По этому по умолчанию я считал что там все ок. Только когда я исправлял входные данные похоже случайно убрал return. А когда ошибка вылезла подумал на return в Handler, нежелеи на контроллер 
Спасибо